# Google analytics URL is being blocked by CSP in Firefox while the blocked URL is allowed in CSP

Tags: firefox, google-analytics, content-security-policy

There is a CSP (`Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only`) defined in our web app which is working in an iframe. This CSP allows `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`in a script-src directive. In spite of this, we are receiving a huge amount of CSP reports about blocking the `https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js`. This only happens in Firefox (74-78) on various operating systems: Windows 10, Linux(Ubunu) and macOS (we see this in sentry.io, where all of our CSP reports collected). Here is an example of such a report.

```
{
  "csp-report": {
    "blocked_uri": "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js",
    "referrer": "",
    "violated_directive": "script-src",
    "document_uri": "https://ourappdomain.herokuapp.com",
    "original_policy": "style-src 'report-sample' 'unsafe-inline' https://ourappdomain.herokuapp.com https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/css/aui.min.css https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/css/aui-experimental.min.css; script-src 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' https://ourappdomain.herokuapp.com https://bitbucket.org/atlassian-connect/all.js https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui.min.js https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui-soy.min.js https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui-experimental.min.js https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/6.0.0/js/aui-datepicker.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.8.0/lodash.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js; form-action 'none'; connect-src https://ourappdomain.herokuapp.com https://api.bitbucket.org https://sentry.io https://www.google-analytics.com https://d301sr5gafysq2.cloudfront.net; img-src https:; font-src https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com; object-src 'none'; default-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'",
    "effective_directive": "script-src"
  }
}
```

Why this can happen?

Comment: This issue seems to be very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638524/content-security-policy-is-blocking-uri-in-allowed-domain

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638524/content-security-policy-is-blocking-uri-in-allowed-domain but I can't mark as a duplicate because it doesn't have an accepted answer, and I'm not allowed to answer because there's a duplicate. 

Helping is increasingly more difficult on stackoverflow than it used to be :/

</rant>