# Script-src-elem being reported although script-src is defined

Tags: content-security-policy

Related: [Why is script-src-elem not using values from script-src as a fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback)

I am seeing a low of CSP reports where e.g. `https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/` is blocked due to the effective directive `script-src-elem`. As you can see in the policy below I am not defining `script-src-elem` but expect it to fall back to `script-src` or even `default-src`. That is my in my debugging this policy looks the way it does.

I have not been able to reproduce the report myself.

Full report:

```
{
    "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "https://www.example.com/some/uri",
        "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com browser.sentry-cdn.com *.youtube.com i.ytimg.com sentry.io images.prismic.io *.atdmt.com *.adnxs.com *.google.se *.google.com *.facebook.com connect.facebook.net *.hotjar.com hotjar.io *.hotjar.io *.adform.net www.google-analytics.com www.gstatic.com www.googletagmanager.com stats.g.doubleclick.net;script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: fonts.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com browser.sentry-cdn.com *.youtube.com i.ytimg.com sentry.io images.prismic.io *.atdmt.com *.adnxs.com *.google.se *.google.com *.facebook.com connect.facebook.net *.hotjar.com hotjar.io *.hotjar.io *.adform.net www.google-analytics.com www.gstatic.com www.googletagmanager.com stats.g.doubleclick.net;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: fonts.gstatic.com *.googleapis.com browser.sentry-cdn.com *.youtube.com i.ytimg.com sentry.io images.prismic.io *.atdmt.com *.adnxs.com *.google.se *.google.com *.facebook.com connect.facebook.net *.hotjar.com hotjar.io *.hotjar.io *.adform.net www.google-analytics.com www.gstatic.com www.googletagmanager.com stats.g.doubleclick.net;img-src 'self' * data:;report-uri https://example.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly",
        "blocked-uri": "https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/"
    }
}
```

I am only seeing it in the chrome browser on primarily Windows. There is a bug [1] report in the Chromium tracker but that was closed off without further investigation and seem to affect something else.

Is there something wrong with my policy or perhaps a bug should be opened in the tracker again?

[1] https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=880816

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Script-src-elem* being reported although *script-src* is defined

- Chrome acts strongly with comply to CSP3 spec, it reports the [*violated-directive* as *effective-directive*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#deprecated-serialize-violation). Chrome sends *effective-directive* where violation should occurred if such directive will be presented in the policy.
- Firefox despite CSP3 spec does send a really *violated-directive* as it appears in the policy. This will contain the default-src directive in the case of violations caused by falling back to the default sources when enforcing a directive.
- The browser **console** always displays the actually violated directive as it present in the policy.

Therefore in case of policy:

```
default-src 'none'
```

- Chrome sends a `script-src-elem` for `<script>` and `<script src=>`, and sends a `script-src-attr` for inline event handlers and javascript:-navigation, except one [bug](https://csplite.com/csp/test339/) (this bug does not touch your CSP since inline scripts are allowed).
- Forefox sends a `default-src` in the violation report.

*Whose behaviour is more useful is an open question, but I prefer Firefoxes one.
 Because Chrome can make crazy anyone who looking for the cause of violations in the case of a long chain of fallback directives, such as in the case of the [Worker](https://csplite.com/csp/test321/#test), especially when some browsers skip some fallback directives in this chain.*

> 

So here we don't even need to "go to the doctor", in your case the script-src is really used for any scripts.

The right question is **why `https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/` is occasionally blocked in the `script-src` directive despite the `*.adform.net` source is specified in it**.

Since the situation cannot be reproduced, the only way is analyze the statistics - user agents and IPs.

If IP belongs to public hosting, you can just ignore such violations - it's a bots.

If is blocking the only one URL `https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/`, it could be some browser "privacy" extensions like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64488667/12865944), because this URL is a tracker.

Is the `browser.sentry-cdn.com` source mean you use a [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript)? Does sentry shows the CSP errors? It should catch those, because CSP violations has built-in javascript errors handlers via [SecurityPolicyViolationEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SecurityPolicyViolationEvent).

PS: I have met only one odd "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36" which blocked all HTTPS: sources. As as it was seen from the `original-policy`, this user agent just removes all https:// from the policy.

> Is there something wrong with my policy or perhaps a bug should be
> opened in the tracker again?

I do not see anything wrong in your CSP. Anyway it should NOT lock `https://track.adform.net/serving/scripts/trackpoint/async/`.
IMHO to open a bug it need collect some specifics.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the right answer. I created [an example webpage](https://mmazzarolo.com/content-security-policy-violation-examples/external-script.html) to compare the differences in the CSP violation implementation across browsers.