# Content Security Policy blocking an explicitly listed host for script-src-elem violation

Tags: content-security-policy

I've got the following Content-Security-Policy header (formatted for readability - it's actually one entire line, with a few more domains that aren't relevant):

```
default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://www.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://storage.googleapis.com;
img-src 'self' data: https:;
font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
frame-ancestors 'self';
form-action 'self' https:;
object-src 'none';
script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net https://www.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com;
report-uri /csp
```

And with this in place, I'm getting the following report - stating that `https://www.google.com/jsapi` is blocked for violating `script-src-elem`, even though `https://www.google.com` is listed in *both* `default-src` and `script-src-elem`:

```
{
  "csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "[HIDDEN]",
    "referrer": "[HIDDEN]",
    "violated-directive": "script-src-elem",
    "effective-directive": "script-src-elem",
    "original-policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://www.facebook.com https://connect.facebook.net https://storage.googleapis.com; img-src 'self' data: https:; font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; frame-ancestors 'self'; form-action 'self' https:; object-src 'none'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://storage.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net https://www.google.com https://maps.googleapis.com; report-uri /csp",
    "disposition": "report", 
    "blocked-uri": "https://www.google.com/jsapi",
    "status-code": 0,
    "script-sample": ""
  }
}
```

Why is this considered a failure according to the policy?

Comment: Hi your policy seems alright. Although it's not a really safe policy. I would also suggest to check if your host has https which you run your policy on. Probably you already verified that the latest policy is in place but please do that aswell (maybe by adding a star to your ``script-src *;``

Comment: @MaxVisser yeah, I'm aware it's not particularly safe - it's a legacy site, to make this CSP more limiting and have everything still work would require a _lot_ of work, so that's probably not going to happen soon. My host is using HTTPS for everything (HSTS header is in place), and this policy is the latest. Thanks for the tip about script-src :)

Comment: you could look into adding a nonce dynamically in apache/nginx; this will make your policy alot more secure as you don't need to manually add all the external hosts to your policy; In nginx you can accomplish this using a subfilter

Answer (score 1):

It is likely another instance of what is described here: : [Why is script-src-elem not using values from script-src as a fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback)

Does this happen to all users or do you just get reports from some of them? You will get reports due to browser extensions, various products that alter content, different CSP implementations in browsers, hijacked browsers etc. Most of these are not relevant if only a fraction of users report them.