# Content-Security-Policy violation reported on allowed image

Tags: security, http-headers, google-tag-manager, content-security-policy

We're attempting to setup a Content-Security-Policy on a website that has *a lot* of Google Tag Manager tags and custom scripts and other random things on it. We're frequently receiving CSP reports like the following:

```
{
   "csp-report":{
      "document-uri":"https://www.example.com/variouspages.php",
      "referrer":"",
      "violated-directive":"img-src",
      "effective-directive":"img-src",
      "original-policy":"[...] img-src 'self' px.ads.linkedin.com [...]",
      "disposition":"enforce",
      "blocked-uri":"https://px.ads.linkedin.com/collect?v=2&amp;fmt=js&amp;pid=0000000&amp;time=1626965954064&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fmy-account%2Fvariouspages.php",
      "status-code":0,
      "script-sample":""
   }
}
```

And I'm very confused by this. When I visit the page, I see the LinkedIn pixel added without a problem, and with CSP warnings - which is what I expect since its domain is in the `img-src` directive.

What could potentially be causing this to be blocked and reported by so many users? I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to blocked domain name: `px.ADS.linkedin.com`. What you observe is the result of work of ads blockers (uBlock / Adblock browser extensions).
Technical details why it's looks that allowed domain is blocked, are explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback/64488667#64488667) post.