# form-action CSP blocking allowed URL

Tags: google-chrome, content-security-policy

Login form is blocked by CSP and I don't understand why

Chrome Version 94.0.4606.61

Error message :

> Refused to send form data to
> 'https://subdomain.mydomain.com/login/local' because it
> violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action
> 'self' https: *.mydomain.com".

No problem with firefox

Answer (score 11):

This is because during login you perform a redirect through the host-source whose is not allowed in the `form-action` directive (the port, the scheme, domain/subdomain name does not match).
When redirecting, the CSP checks the entire chain of sources, but browsers have differences in the behavior of [`form-action` for redirects](https://csplite.com/csp75/#inconsistence):

- **Chrome/Safari** consider a redirect when submitting a form to be potentially dangerous, since sensitive user data can be redirected to an attacker's domain. Therefore, they block redirection if host-source (domain) not allowed in the `form-actions` are participate in the chain of redirects.
- **Firefox** believes that the server redirect is under the control of the owner of the page protected in CSP. Therefore, during redirect it allows you to send the form during redirect even to third-party domains.

> 

Note 1. `'self'` means exact `scheme://domain:port` from the Url in the address bar. Therefore CSP:

```
 form-action 'self' https: *.mydomain.com
```

- In case Url is `HTTPS://subdomain.mydomain.com` the above CSP is become `form-action HTTPS://subdomain.mydomain.com https: HTTPS://*.mydomain.com` whis is equal to `form-action https:` - it allows anything except `http:`-Urls.
- In case Url is `HTTP://subdomain.mydomain.com`, the above CSP is become `form-action HTTP://subdomain.mydomain.com https: HTTP://*.mydomain.com` and it does not allow a main domain `mydomain.com`.

> 

Note 2. The Url `https://subdomain.mydomain.com/login/local` in the message:

> Refused to send form data to 'https://subdomain.mydomain.com/login/local' because it violates ...`

is <s>not</s> Url **really** blocked by Chrome. This is just the first Url in the redirect chain.

> 

Note 3. If CSP, after all, blocks the allowed domain, it is most likely that it's [interference of browser extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback/64488667#64488667) such as NoScript/uBlock/AdBlock/PrivacyBadger, etc. interfere.

Comment: Wasn't even dreaming about an answer like this. Thanks a lot.
But if all URLs in the redirect chain have the same domain and are https, why Chrome is blocking them ?

Comment: Check which browser extensions you have installed. Extensions such as NoScript/adblock/adblock can have the [effect of blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback/64488667#64488667) a seemingly whitelisted source. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I think Safari, like Firefox, [doesn't block redirects](https://wpt.fyi/results/content-security-policy/form-action/form-action-src-redirect-blocked.sub.html?run_id=5694712078925824&run_id=5066726120095744&run_id=5733191831781376&run_id=5716967106281472).