Content Security Policy form-action issue can't submit to different parts of the same website with 'self' flag
There is a page on one subfolder of a website, the page has a bunch of forms on it, going to different places that are child locations of the form.
This works fine.
There is one form that submits to another part of the same website, and this also worked fine, but now in Chrome and Edge the form to the other [sister] part of same website fails to submit with the notice:

Refused to send form data to 'OURDOMAIN.net/sales/printlist.php' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".

But all other forms to other child elements of the form page location all work. How can this be fixed?
CSP:
(.htaccess)
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests; default-src 'self' https:; ...  form-action 'self' ;"

HTML:
HTML page location is OURDOMAIN.net/subfolder/index.html


    <table width="70%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="306"><label for='cat'>Add New</label></td>
                    <td width="384"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="add1.php" accept-charset="UTF-8"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="submit()">
                                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value='1'>Some options</option>
                                <option value='2'>THIS WORKS</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
                        </form>    
                        </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for='cat2'>List by Category</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <select name="catlist" id="cat2" onchange="submit()">
                                                             <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value='1'>Some options</option>
                                <option value='2'>THIS WORKS</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
                        </form>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for='search'>Search by Code</label></td>
                    <td>
                        <form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input name="search" type="text" placeholder='This works' 
                            id="search" size="12" maxlength="36" >
                            <input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Submit" >
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><label for='cat3'>PRINTABLE List by</label></td>
                    <td><form action="/sales/printlist.php" method="post" name="form4" id="form4" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <select name="cat" id="cat3" onchange="submit()">
                                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                                <option value='1'>Some options</option>
                               <option value='3'>THIS DOES NOT WORK</option>
                            </select>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
                        </form></td>
                </tr>
               
            </table>



Attempts to solve:
I have tried to edit the CSF file and add the domain name explicitly as well as adding the full URL of the destination;

CSF: form-action 'self' https://OURDOMAIN.net/sales/printlist.php ;

But this does does not change the error.
I have also tried to edit the HTML "action" destination:
<form action="../sales/printlist.php" method="post"...

But this does does not change the error.
Extra details:

On Firefox this error does not occur.
This occurs on Chrome and Edge browsers.
The CSP as far as I can tell is formatted correctly.
Form submitted URL : OurDomain.net/subfolder/index.html
Form receiving URL : OurDomain.net/sales/printlist.php
There are various other forms across the website. So CSP changes can't be specific for this form alone.

How should we fix this so Google Chrome submits the form?

Does any redirect happen after form submission?

This would appear to be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433198/form-action-csp-blocking-allowed-url

@HalvorSakshaug nope, no redirection occurs.

@DougReeder yes I'd seen that but I didn't find documentation that directing forms to a sister folder on the same domain was going to cause these failures. It seems unnecessarily specific if so. Anywho I fixed the issue by copying the destination address file to the same folder as the form submitted. Still, would like to know the process that causes this issue
