# CSP: What all has an impact on the CSP-Reports

Tags: content-security-policy

We are using an Elasticstack as an endpoint for the CSP reports.
The majority of the reports, indicate CSP violations that we can't reproduce.

1. e.g. access to the google tag manager is prevented because entries in script-src are missing - although this entry is stored in our CSP. Just one example.
2. there are also reports with an outdated policy in the original-policy: we had the directive 'prefetch-src' in use for one day about 2 weeks ago. After that we removed it.
   However, this directive still appears in some reports.

What is the reason for this behavior? According to research, bots, browser extensions or the respective ISP play a big role, because they inject code into the website, which then violates the CSP.

What else can have an influence on this behavior as described in points 1 and 2?

Comment: I think this might be caused by specific browser extensions on the user's browser, but I am not sure.

Comment: You also might want to post the second question in new thread to focus on one specific question.

Comment: moved the scond question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659130/csp-reports-best-practice-to-handle-false-positive-csp-reports-with-logstash

Comment: I have answered your original second question here since this other one you posted (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659130) is slightly different

Answer (score 4):

I've struggled with the same and I've also struggled to find good resources on mysterious CSP reports. Some of my top suspects are:

1. Different browser implementations, especially embedded versions and minor browsers and their translator function
2. Extensions benign or malign
3. Corporate security products
4. Fonts overriding defaults

Many of the others remain a mystery that I simply don't have the time to try to understand. I suggest to disregard issues that can't be reproduced in recent versions of popular browsers, only appear for certain combinations of browser and OS, are infrequent, or seem to be caused by a very small subset of users (usually limited in time).

The best resource I've found for your first question is this: [Why is script-src-elem not using values from script-src as a fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback#64488667) I believe PrivacyBadger is an example of this behavior as I've seen variations (script-src/script-src-elem) of these reports.

Regarding your second question I have seen reports coming several days after a change to CSP. I suspect caching somewhere, most likely in the browser or someone leaving a page open.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question:

> 2. there are also reports with an outdated policy in the original-policy:
>    we had the directive 'prefetch-src' in use for one day about 2 weeks
>    ago. After that we removed it. However, this directive still appears
>    in some reports.

There's a possible explanation depending on the way you have implemented the CSP.
If you are adding headers on the response of the index.html in the backend using some service (e.g a CDN, a reverse proxy), then be aware that browsers
may still reach into their cache when you update the headers themselves.

This is at least the behavior I've see in chrome when we serve our resources from AWS S3. The initial request for the app returns with 304 "not modified" and although the resource appears in the devtools with new headers, CSP errors are still being reported.

In order to force the browser to adhere to the rules you must replace the index.html with a new one (and make sure its content has also been changed).