# Content-Security-Policy blocking calls irrespective of directives

Tags: content-security-policy

I have my current directive configured as

> script-src 'self' https://testcdn-a.akamaihd.net 'unsafe-inline'
> style-src 'self' https://testcdn-a.akamaihd.net 'unsafe-inline'

I have setup to add **Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only** and I see report that calls are getting blocked with the below information

**violated directive** - script-src-elem

**blocked-host** - testcdn-a.akamaihd.net

**blocked-path** - /v/static/mixpanel-2-2-1b.js

Why is **testcdn-a.akamaihd.net** still getting blocked ?

Comment: Without having the actual markup and hand, this is just a guess: It seems that the scripts loaded from the CDN try to embed and load additional resource. `'strict-dynamic'` might help here (https://content-security-policy.com/strict-dynamic/). Google Maps integration has a similar problem, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/content-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this and know of the following explanations

1. The given URL causes a redirect chain where some resource down the chain is blocked, but the blocked host is still the first element of the chain. Check if it redirects to another host.
2. The linked answer to this question: [Why is script-src-elem not using values from script-src as a fallback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback#64488667)