# Why does CSP block a file that's explicitly allowed?

Tags: express, content-security-policy

Some time ago, the app I am working on has turned on stricter CSP against script elements. The configuration for it (using package `helmet` in an `express` based server) looks roughly like this:

```js
module.exports = helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: {
    reportOnly: false,
    useDefaults: false,
    directives: {
      "report-uri": "/api/csp-violation-report",
      "script-src": [
        "'self'",
        "'report-sample'",
        // some domains here...
        "https://connect-cdn.atl-paas.net/all.js", // <- important
        // more sources...
        (req, res) => `'nonce-${res.locals.nonce}'`,
      ],
      "default-src": "* 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:",
    }
  }
})
```

As you can see here, we allow scripts to be loaded only from specific sources (one of this sources being Atlassian's https://connect-cdn.atl-paas.net/all.js script file) or using specific nonce if they are inline. We also request that in case of CSP violation, the browser should send a violation report to the provided URL. The reports we get are then checked and filtered (because we found out that 99% of those reports are useless, but that's another story) and if they pass our filters, they are written to logs with the intention of further investigation.

To my surprise, this is a report that I found today:

```json
{
  blocked-uri: "https://connect-cdn.atl-paas.net/all.js"
  document-uri: "[redacted]"
  effective-directive: "script-src-elem"
  original-policy: "report-uri /api/csp-violation-report;script-src 'self' 'report-sample' [redacted] https://connect-cdn.atl-paas.net/all.js [redacted] 'nonce-xxxxx';default-src * 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:"
  script-sample: ""
  violated-directive: "script-src-elem"
}
```

What I find troubling is that the `blocked-uri` is exactly the Atlassian's script I mentioned earlier which is added to allowed sources. And there's no way that for some reason it was not included in headers, because it is right there in the same report, under `original-policy`. So to me looks like the same report says a resource was blocked by a policy that explicitly says it should have been allowed.

According to the logs this happens for a very small fraction of users and there's no definitive browser sending those.

### The wrapping-up question

Shall this report be treated as a legitimate indication that something might not work for the users? Is it possible that browser send incorrect reports? Or maybe something was misconfigured or overlooked?
I also assume that this report might have been just a result of bad actor sending us fake data (unless I miss something, there's no way to prevent anyone from doing that), but before I acknowledge this as what's happening, I wonder if that's something else.

Thanks!

Comment: The top answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322419/why-is-script-src-elem-not-using-values-from-script-src-as-a-fallback is the best explanation I've found.

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug thank you for this link. While it might not be exact same case, it definitely confirms that despite heavy filtering applied, there is still a lot of cases I wouldn't even thought about. Which, if you ask me, makes this potentially useful feature completely unsuitable for prod use cases - shame, but welp. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: It is a violation of script-src-elem, which is a directive you haven't implemented. This is a clear sign that this is not a problem with your policy and the content on your site. As it also happens to a fraction of users I would just ignore it.

Comment: Well, according to MDN, `script-src-elem` by default fallbacks to `script-src`, so it's also weird. And yeah I wanted to ignore it, but it - and similar ones - kept spamming our logs so we had to keep adding additional filtering rules, up to the point we decided it makes no sense to have those report.